# Gyroscopes Android issues

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I'm using Android's gyroscope and iOS's gyroscope in a unity project I'm making. I'm struggling however, to deal with difference in functionality between the two. When starting a gyroscope in an application on iOS, it tracks how much rotation you've done from a certain point, i.e. it calibrates itself to whatever direction you're facing and determines that whatever direction that is, is the default.

With Android's gyroscope, it doesn't calibrate itself, so dependent what direction you are facing, you can receive drastically different readouts.

I'd like to copy the functionality of Apple's and use it on Android. I'm taking a starting quartenion which reads what direction the user is facing when the user first starts the app and assigns it to a global variable. I'm struggling however to know what to do with this variable.

Any help would be appreciated.